# Помогите разбить текст регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Есть файл с функциями и процедурами VBA. Надо вытащить первые их строки при помощи регулярного выражения.

```
my $s = 'Public Function SheetReMake(ByVal sheetName As String) As Worksheet \' создает новую таблицу, если такая есть, то ее удаляет';
my @arr = ($s =~ m/^((public|private)*\s*(function|sub)+\s+(\w+)\(.*?\)(.*?))+$/igm);
print $#arr."\n";
for my $i(0..$#arr) {
    print $arr[$i]."\n";
}
```

Вместо этого в массив `@arr` попадают отдельно "Public", "Private", "Sub", "Function" и т.д., а также целые искомые строки. Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: У вас все группы с захватом. Если группа не нужна в результате ставьте после открывающейся скобки `?:` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8

Comment: Спасибо! Уже легче, но теперь ищет не все вхождения, пока не соображу, почему.

Comment: И теперь невозможно обращаться к данным из групп - $1...$5.
Сейчас выглядит так
    my @arr = ($s =~ /^((?:public|private)*\s*(?:function|sub)+\s+(?:\w+)\\(.*?\\)(?:.*?))+$/igm);

Comment: А вы кстати в вопросе не написали нужны вам данные их групп или нет. ведь предложенный `?:` все что делает - это делает данные скобки не захватываемыми

Comment: Mea culpa... Наверно, надо вначале без захвата подстрок получить массив строк, потом в цикле его разбирать и работать с ним дальше.
Тут вначале строки public или private могут быть, а могут быть опущены, если есть, то за ними пробел, потом обязательное слово function или sub, затем пробел и обязательное слово - имя функции и обязательные скобки (пустые или со списком аргументов). Если это функция, то за ней тип возвращаемых данных и необязательный комментарий, отделенный одиночной кавычкой.

Answer (score 1):

Используемый вами способ обработки строки выделает каждую отдельную группу захвата в отдельный элемент результирующего массива. В итоге в цикле вы видите каждый элемент отдельно. Если необходимо отдельно работать с выделяемыми группами захвата, то можно использовать например синтаксис обхода регулярного выражения с помощью while:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $s = 'Public Function SheetReMake(ByVal sheetName As String) As Worksheet \' создает новую таблицу, если такая есть, то ее удаляет';
while($s =~ /((public|private)*\s*(function|sub)+\s+(\w+)\(.*?\)(.*?))/igm) {
  print "Тип: ",$2,"  F/S:",$3," Имя:",$4," Весь текст:",$1,"\n";
}
```

Пример на [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/clRbag)

Comment: Спасибо! Это более элегантно, чем моя мысль с промежуточным массивом.

Answer (score 1):

А можно получить сразу массив без использования циклов. Для этого просто захватываем нужный нам текст (наподобие lookbehind).

```
@matched =  $text =~ m/(?:private|public)(?:.*$)\n(.*$)/igm;
```

Здесь мы:

1. Захватываем строки, которые содержат `private|public`
2. Игнорируем то, что словили `?:`
3. Игнорируем весь текст до конца строки `(?:.*$)`
4. Ловим перенос строки `\n`
5. Захватываем следующую строку `(.*$)`

`i` -- игнорируем разницу в заглавных буквах
`g` -- не останавливаемся на первом совпадении
`m` -- Меняем смысл для `^$`, теперь они ловят начало/конец строк в середине переданного текста

---

В вашем примере, по сути не хватает игнорирования. Т.е. приблизительно вот так должно быть:

```
/(?:public|private)*\s*(?:function|sub)+\s+(\w+)\(.*?\)(.*?)/igm
```

Теперь ключевые слова не будут словлены

Comment: @klaus65sem: Этот ответ всё ещё не решает ваш вопрос?